Google Analytic data that are not synced on Big Query
I need some advice regarding GA4 data. We’re reporting GA4 numbers for 2023 using the GA frontend, where we can access the full year’s data. However, in BigQuery, our data only starts from ‘2023-06-12,’ and we don’t have the earlier data from ‘2023-01-01.’ Is it possible to request or retrieve the missing data in BigQuery?
